# How to create login for member area only

Tags: session, coldfusion-10

I am creating an ecommerce website for my project work. In which I have created one application.cfm page, using the code from [this tutorial](http://tutorial8.easycfm.com):

```
<!--- Create the application --->
        <cfapplication name="MyApp"
            clientmanagement="Yes"
            sessionmanagement="Yes"
            sessiontimeout="#CreateTimeSpan(0,0,0,10)#"
            applicationtimeout="#CreateTimeSpan(0,0,0,10)#" />

        <!--- Now define that this user is logged out by default --->
        <CFPARAM NAME="session.allowin" DEFAULT="false" />

        <!--- Now define this user id to zero by default, this will be used later on to access specific information about this user. --->
        <CFPARAM NAME="session.user_id" DEFAULT="0" />

        <!--- Now if the variable "session.allowin" does not equal true, send user to the login page --->
        <!--- the other thing you must check for is if the page calling this application.cfm is the "login.cfm" page and the "Login_process.cfm" page since the Application.cfm is always called, if this is not checked the application will simply Loop over and over. To check that, you do the following call --->

        <cfif session.allowin neq "true">
            <cfif  ListLast(CGI.SCRIPT_NAME, "/") EQ "loginn.cfm">
            <cfelseif ListLast(CGI.SCRIPT_NAME, "/") EQ "login_process.cfm">
            <cfelse>
                <!--- this user is not logged in, alert user and redirect to the login.cfm page --->
                <script>
                    alert("You must login to access this area!");
                    self.location="loginn.cfm";
                </script>
            </cfif>
        </cfif>
```

This is the Login_process.cfm page:

```
<!--- Get all records from the database that match this users credentials --->
    <cfquery name="qVerify" datasource="cfdb2">
        SELECT   User_name, User_pass
        FROM    uid_pass
        WHERE User_name = '#name#'
     and  User_pass='#pass#'
    </cfquery>

    <cfif qVerify.RecordCount>
        <!--- This user has logged in correctly, change the value of the session.allowin value --->   
          <cfset session.allowin = "True" />

        <cfset session.User_name = qVerify.User_name />

        <!--- Now welcome user and redirect to "<strong>members_only.cfm</strong>" --->
        <script>
            alert("Welcome user, you have been successfully logged in!");
            self.location="index.cfm";
        </script>
    < cfelse>
        <!--- this user did not log in correctly, alert and redirect to the login page --->
        <script>
            alert("Your credentials could not be verified, please try again!!!");
            self.location="Javascript:history.go(-1)";
        </script>
    </cfif>
```

The problem I am facing with the code is when I open up the index page it asks me to login. Without logging in, I cannot proceed. If I open the registration.cfm page directly, the same thing happens. How can I structure the code so that a guest can access things, but must login when they use the "Add to Cart" option.

Comment: Stop using Application.cfm, start using Application.cfc.

Answer (score 1):

So you need to 'whitelist' any page that can be accessed without being logged in. Something like:

```
<cfif session.allowin neq "true">
    <!--- check if this is a page that doesn't require authentication --->
    <cfset currentScript = ListLast(CGI.SCRIPT_NAME, "/")>
    <cfif listFindNoCase("login.cfm,registration.cfm,login_process.cfm", currentScript) eq 0>
        <!--- redirect to login.cfm page --->
        <cflocation addtoken="false" href="login.cfm">
    </cfif>
</cfif>
```

I notice that you are using Application.cfm, really you should be using Application.cfc. Then you can tap into the application lifecycle. Your security checks can be in the `onRequestStart` method, you can set up sessions in the `onSessionStart` method etc.

Always use `cfqueryparam` in queries to protect yourself from SQL injection attacks. Something like:

```
<cfquery name="qVerify" datasource="cfdb2">
    SELECT   User_name, User_pass
    FROM    uid_pass
    WHERE User_name = <cfqueryparam value="#name#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
       and  User_pass = <cfqueryparam value="#pass#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
</cfquery>
```

I'd also suggest that you read up on storing passwords, as from your code it looks like you are storing your passwords in the database in plain text - this is bad. You want to have a look at using one-way password encryption.